# Type cannot be serialized - Working in unmanaged code, failing in managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, json, unmanaged-package

I'm working with the following JSON:

```
{
  "compositeRequest" : [ {
    "url" : "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/Case",
    "referenceId" : "Parent",
    "method" : "POST",
    "body" : {
      "Origin" : "Phone",
      "Priority" : "Medium",
      "Subject" : "Initial Case",
      "Description" : ""
    }
  }, {
    "url" : "/services/data/v58.0/query?q=SELECT Id,CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id ='@{Parent.id}'",
    "referenceId" : "Cases",
    "method" : "GET",
    "body": null
  } ],
  "collateSubrequests" : false,
  "allOrNone" : false
}
```

It is a Composite API Request. Here's the wrapper class:

```
public class CompositeRequest {

    public Boolean allOrNone;
    public Boolean collateSubrequests;
    public List<SubRequest> compositeRequest;

    public CompositeRequest() {
        this.allOrNone = false;
        this.collateSubrequests = false;
        this.compositeRequest = new List<SubRequest>();
    }

    public compositeRequest setSubRequests(List<SubRequest> compositeRequest) {
        this.compositeRequest = compositeRequest;
        return this;
    }

    public class SubRequest {

        public String method;
        public String url;
        public String referenceId;
        public Object body; // polymorphic variable to accomodate for child records

        public SubRequest setMethod(String method) {
            this.method = method;
            return this;
        }

        public SubRequest setURL(String url) {
            this.url = url;
            return this;
        }

        public SubRequest setReference(String referenceId) {
            this.referenceId = referenceId;
            return this;
        }

        public SubRequest setBody(Object body) {
            this.body = body; // Could be the Body class or a Map<String, Object>
            return this;
        }
    }

    public class Body {
        public Boolean allOrNone;
        public List<Map<String, Object>> records;
    }
}
```

Here's the class for Serialization of `CompositeRequest`:

```
public class Request {

    Object request; //Generic object as this a reusable class 

    public Request setRequest(Object request) {
        this.request = request;
        return this;
    }

    public String serialize() {
        return JSON.serialize(this.request);
    }
}
```

I understand that 'Object' is not exactly a favorable Data Type for JSON Serialization. My confusion is this code  `JSON.serialize(this.request);` is working fine as unmanaged code but is failing in the managed package and I'm not sure why, any ideas?

Error message:

> **Type cannot be serialized**

The solution to fix this just to accept a stable 'Object' such as the `CompositeRequest' instance and Serialize that.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain the reason for the difference in behavior between unmanaged and managed code.

**Edit on 04/09:**

Debug log (`this.request`) for both Managed and Unmanaged

```
CompositeRequest:[allOrNone=false, collateSubrequests=false, compositeRequest=(SubRequest:[body={Description=, Origin=Phone, Priority=Medium, Status=Working, Subject=Initial Case}, method=POST, referenceId=Parent, url=/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/Case], SubRequest:[body=null, method=GET, referenceId=Cases, url=/services/data/v58.0/query?q=SELECT Id,CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id ='@{Parent.id}'])]
```

`CompositeRequestGenerator` class:

```
public with sharing class CompositeRequestGenerator {

    private String version;
    private String baseURL;
    private String objectName;

    private CompositeRequest request;
    private List<CompositeRequest.SubRequest> compositeRequest;


    public CompositeRequestGenerator(String objectName, String baseURL, String version) {
        this.objectName = objectName;
        this.baseURL = baseURL;
        this.version = version;
        this.request = new CompositeRequest();
        this.compositeRequest = new List<CompositeRequest.SubRequest>();
    }

    public CompositeRequest getRequest() {
        this.request.setSubRequests(this.compositeRequest);
        return this.request;
    }


    public CompositeRequestGenerator setInitialSubRequest(Map<String, Object> payload) {
        CompositeRequest.SubRequest subRequest = new CompositeRequest.SubRequest();
        subRequest.setMethod('POST');
        subRequest.setURL(this.buildParentURL());
        subRequest.setReference('Parent');
        subRequest.setBody(payload);
        this.compositeRequest.add(subRequest);
        return this;
    }

    public CompositeRequestGenerator setQuery(String objectName, List<String> fields) {
        CompositeRequest.SubRequest subRequest = new CompositeRequest.SubRequest();
        subRequest.setMethod('GET');
        subRequest.setURL(this.baseURL + 'v' + this.version + '/query?q=' + this.buildQuery(objectName, fields));
        subRequest.setReference(objectName + 's');
        this.compositeRequest.add(subRequest);
        return this;
    }

    private String buildParentURL() {
        return this.baseURL + 'v' + this.version + '/sobjects/' + this.objectName;
    }

    private String buildChildURL() {
        return this.baseURL + 'v' + this.version + '/composite/sobjects';
    }

    private String buildQuery(String objectName, List<String> fields) {
        return 'SELECT Id,' + String.join(fields, ',') + ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE Id =\'@{Parent.id}\'';
    }

}
```

Note: `setInitialSubRequest` is taking a Map of String to SObject value that will be passed onto `SubRequest.body` and `setQuery` is not using the `body` attribute of `SubRequest`, setting the `body` will result in the failed callout for the `GET` call.  `SubRequest.body` is a generic object as more request of type `POST` could be set in the JSON.

Hope this helps!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to debug `System.debug(this.request);` in both managed and unmanaged packages? Could you please add the debug here?

Comment: I ran this in my managed package org.  No errors. Worked perfectly.  Are you able to add the logic on how you created your `CompositeRequest`? Specifically, what is your `body`? Does your managed package org have Cases in it?

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova I have modified my question to include logs

Comment: @NickCook  I have modified my question to the class that generates the request.

Comment: I don't see the log, there is a json sample the same as on the top on the question. i meant you to add debug of the object (before serialization).

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova added, Please note the log result is the same for both managed and unmanaged code

Comment: have you tried to use SubRequest as a separate stand-alone class instead of inner class? I know there used be problems with Aura, LWC and inner classes.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work : ( @Patlatus

Comment: can you minify it into Minimum reproducable example? How do you initiate request? Can you show all the chain which call the line that fails with `Type cannot be serialized`? How do you initialize Request class and how do you call Request.serialize?

Comment: Actually is your class even called 'Request'? When I try to construct it, I receive an error "Compile Error: Abstract classes cannot be constructed: System.Request at line 9 column 21", looks like it is confused with System.Request class

Comment: Actually I tried to replicate it in my package with the following initialization code and this worked for me inside the managed package https://gist.github.com/bdovh/991de687ede8b35ca1d90a1195884eed, with no serialization issues. Can you try to copy that code and tell us if you see any issues with that?

Comment: @Patlatus what I have posted is the minimum code. I can tell you when I switch the `Object request`  in `Request` to `CompositeRequest` it's working fine. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: well, I had Object request in Request but didn't have any problems

Comment: Maybe you are setupping the records in a different way? Have you tried to check if my initialization works fine without errors for you? I stil haven't seen your Minimum reproducible code example (you may look for reference in my gist what I mean by that)